# Как использовать PostgreSQL в java?

Tags: java, postgresql

Объясните, пожалуйста, доступным языком, как использовать PostgreSQL в java. Пользуюсь NetBeans. Если есть какая-то пошаговая инструкция буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Идёте на страницу [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/)
2. Качаете нужный jar
3. Подключаете его к проекту
4. Используете